# Combine SQL queries with different WHERE causes

Tags: sql

I have written a database with game stats, featuring winner, loser, and money won. I'm now trying to make stats for it.

[See database here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tyzhl.png)

I'm trying to make stats for these games, etc number of wins/losses for player, and money lost and money won.

Till now I have found three queries to achieve this.

```
SELECT COUNT(winner) AS wins, COUNT(loser) AS losses 
FROM coinflipper_games 
WHERE winner = "dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3" 
   OR loser = "dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3"

SELECT SUM(money) 
FROM coinflipper_games 
WHERE winner = "dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3"

SELECT SUM(money) 
FROM coinflipper_games 
WHERE loser = "dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3"
```

The problem is, it's in no way effective using three queries, so I'm trying to reduce this to one. Does anyone have any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(case when winner='dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' then 1 else 0 end) AS wins, 
       SUM(case when loser='dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' then 1 else 0 end)  AS losses,
       SUM(CASE WHEN winner = 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' THEN money ELSE 0 END) as winnings,
       SUM(CASE WHEN loser = 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' THEN money ELSE 0 END) as losings
  FROM coinflipper_games
 WHERE winner='dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' 
    OR loser='dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3'
```

Comment: Thank you, makes so much more sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(winner) AS wins, COUNT(loser) AS losses,
       SUM(CASE WHEN winner = 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' THEN money ELSE 0 END) as winnings,
       SUM(CASE WHEN loser = 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' THEN money ELSE 0 END) as losings
FROM coinflipper_games
WHERE 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' IN (winner, loser);
```

Note that I replaced the double quotes with single quotes.  Single quotes are the SQL standard for string delimiters.  This also simplifies the `WHERE` clause.

Note:

The above replicates the queries you have in the question.  You probably actually intend to counts the winners and losers as well as the amounts.  That would be:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN winner = 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as wins,
       SUM(CASE WHEN loser = 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as losses,
       SUM(CASE WHEN winner = 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' THEN money ELSE 0 END) as winnings,
       SUM(CASE WHEN loser = 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' THEN money ELSE 0 END) as losings
FROM coinflipper_games
WHERE 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' IN (winner, loser);
```

Comment: Thank you :)
Never understood how to use CASE, this makes so much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(winner = 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3') AS wins, 
  SUM(loser = 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3') AS losses,
  SUM(money * CASE WHEN winner = 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS total_money  
FROM coinflipper_games 
WHERE 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' IN (winner, loser)
```

The above query will return 1 column for the total `money` that the user won or lost.
If you want 2 different columns:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(winner = 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3') AS wins, 
  SUM(loser = 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3') AS losses,
  SUM(CASE WHEN winner = 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' THEN money ELSE 0 END) AS money_won,
  SUM(CASE WHEN loser = 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' THEN money ELSE 0 END) AS money_lost  
FROM coinflipper_games 
WHERE 'dba92393-5bbd-365f-8fe7-55be2707caf3' IN (winner, loser)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4cbce6a44e066c032cbd7f5e43f583c7).

Comment: Thank you, makes so much more sense now. Two columns was what I had in mind yes :)